# Difficulty in retaining the default visibility of a method which needs to be accessed by the different package

Tags: java, package, public, access-specifier

I am developing a **MineSweeper**. In that I have 3 packages. 1.frontEnd 2.backEnd 3.mineSweeperControl.

**mineSweeperControl** contains an **class ActionSplicer** which implements ActionListener.In **frontEnd** I have an array of JBUTTONS and an array of **ActionSplicer** objects, such that **splicerobj[i][j] listens to button[i][j].(one to one correspondence)**

**backEnd** contains an array of objects such that **object[i][j] has the background details of   button[i][j]** such as MineValue,isCellEmpty,isCellFlagged etc...

Method **doBackgroundAction(i,j){..}**  is defined in **class BackEndManager**.
In **actionPerformed** of **ActionSplicer**, I call **doBackgroundAction(i,j)** so that the any change in foreground will also affect the background.

> **Where my problem is?**
>
> The **doBackGroundAction(i,j)** needs to be public since it is called
>   in different package.

But I don't want any method to be public, since it may reduce the flexibility and then any person can change the values of attributes.

I cannot extend the class BackEndManager since I am creating an array of ActionSplicer objects in frontEnd.

Hence I need some sort of guidance about declaring doBackGroundAction(i,j).
Whether it is right way to declare the methods as public in some non-avoidable situvation?
Or How can I change my design to retain the method with default visibility.

Answer (score 0):

In order to not expose that method as public you could have something like this:

```
public class BackEndManager {
    protected void doBackgroundAction(int i, int j) { ... }
}
```

Then whenever you need the method create a subclass of BackEndManager (since protected allows subclasses to access the method):

```
public class BackEndManagerSubclass extends BackEndManager {
    public void doBackgroundActionNew(int i, int j) {
        doBackgroundAction(i, j);
    }
}
```

This keeps the initial class intact and lets you expose a new method through the subclass that "hides" the real internals of the `BackEndManager` class.

**Edit**: I just saw this line:
"I cannot extend the class BackGroundManager since I am creating an array of ActionSplicer objects in frontEnd."

If by `BackGroundManager` you mean `BackEndManager` then my idea is not useful. Can you please make this point more clear? From what I understand `ActionSplicer` is in the package `mineSweeperControl` and `frontEnd` is another package so what is the connection with `BackEndManager`?